# how to fix the sub-menu getting 100% wide using css

Tags: html, css

I am .net developer and dont know css tricks. I have added a menu found from somewhere and added it here http://delhipitch.com

but I don't remember what I have changed, due to which this menu not working properly.

Somehow, I have found to add z-index using firebug.

div.menu3 ul ul

Now, the only problem I want to get solve is sub-menu coming 100% wide.

Can someone help me what I have to add in css part to correct this.

Any new suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: thanks James for correcting

Comment: Add my code in your css file if any issue i help you  ....

Answer (score 1):

Now add this code

```
.menu3 > ul > li{
position:relative;
}
.menu3 > ul > li > ul {
z-index:100;
left:0;
width:auto;
top:50px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
div.menu3 ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5F6975;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

add:
<strike>width:100%</strike>

```
width: auto;
left:0;
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Oops... I misreading the question... efectively, width must be set `auto` as say the Rohit Azad.